# Hindi text extraction from pdf in android studios

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pdf, kotlin

Hey I'm a bit new to Android studio and I'm having some trouble in extraction non-English (hindi) text from pdf and displaying it in text view. 
The English letters are correctly extracted from pdf but when it comes to non-English (hindi) letter, I always get garbage value
Can anyone please give a sample code as to how to extract the non-English letter from a pdf ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Please post your code here, otherwise your post looks like a 'write my code for me' request, which are not exactly popular on SO.

Comment: Can you post a sample PDF file with Hindi text so we can take a look at it?